# Android: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am getting a NullPointerException in this block of code.I am using Actionbar Sherlock.

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

               Bundle b = new Bundle();
               b.putString("query", query);
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecipeSearchActivity.class);
               i.putExtras(b);
               startActivity(i);
               return true;
           }
```

Here is my LogCat:

```
11-30 15:32:09.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 15:32:09.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1837): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 15:32:09.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1837):     at com.android.yummly.activities.HomeActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(HomeActivity.java:32)
```

My question is, what is trying to be passed as null and why?

Edit: Here is the Menu XML as requested.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/ic_search"
          android:orderInCategory="5"
          android:title="Search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/activity_home"
          android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" />

    <item android:id="@+id/ic_favorites"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorites"
          android:title="@string/ic_favorites"
          android:onClick="onClickFavorites"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: You can use debugger and find easily!

Comment: searchView is probably null. How did you get the searchView? Posting the menu XML would be helpful too.

Comment: Look at `onCreateOptionsMenu` **null** is here.

Comment: I forgot about the debugger..I am an idiot. My bad.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using action bar sherlock. IT has been giving me all sorts of issues. I added the library correctly because everything is fine, but SearchView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this out about Actionbar Sherlock. Only certain combinations work with searchView

Combinations that will work:
Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar with new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext())
Theme.Sherlock.Light or Theme.Sherlock.Light with new SearchView(this)

If you use the theme Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar and create the view with new SearchView(this), it won't work.

Source:https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685#issuecomment-13076236

I fixed my own issue.